# d3.js axis - making it have 0 ticks and no markings

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to create a d3.js axis and have there be no tick marks and no numbering scheme? Basically, can I make the axis invisible? I'm using the code below to create my axes:

```
svg.selectAll("axis")
      .data(d3.range(angle.domain()[1]))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + angle(d) * 180 / Math.PI + ")"; })
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(radius.copy().range([0,0]))
      .ticks(1)
      .orient("left"))
    .append("text")
    .style("color", "white") 
      .attr("y", 
        function (d) {
          if (window.innerWidth < 455){
            console.log("innerWidth less than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(0);
          }
          else{
            console.log("innerWidth greater than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(0);
          }
        })
      .attr("dy", "0em");
```

Comment: can also do .ticks(0) when defining the axis, at least with v3 of d3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your axis to be visible, just don't draw them (basically comment out this code).

If you really just want to turn them white, you can use the following classes:

```
.axis line, .axis text, .axis path {
   color: white;
}
```

This would be the easiest way to manipulate them to turn them 'on' and 'off'. Also, if you ever need to figure out how to style a `d3` diagram, you can navigate through the SVG just like you do html and style with CSS the same way too.

For example, here is the SVG for the tick marks in the `axis`.

```
<line class="tick" y2="6" x2="0"></line>
```

You can see that I targeted the element (`line`) but you could also target (`.tick`) as well.

Comment: I knew somebody would say this. I should have added that I need the axes to be drawn dynamically. Sometimes i want them there, other times I don't. Is there a way to just make the color of the axes and their various appendages (ticks/text) a white or clear color? Thanks